# Webkit Scroll Bar applied to certain element

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am currently trying to apply the Scroll Bar webkit styling to a certain element however, with no luck. I have looked everywhere; There are 2 threads on Stack Overflow I have seen however, do not work.

Most of the threads say to use:

```
.class-name::-webkit-scrollbar { }
```

However I have had not luck with this

This is a full example of what people are reccomending (it doesnt work):
http://codepen.io/wrdle/pen/BQYBjN

If you help it is much appreciated! :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS works just fine - the problem in your CodePen is that the document is scrolling, not the `#container` element, so you don't see its scrollbar.

Add this CSS as an example to see the correct scrollbar:

```
#container {
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/capitalq/pen/MbQgJv

Comment: Is there a way where I wouldn't have to define the height?

Comment: You could just apply the scrollbar styles generically instead of on a specific element: http://codepen.io/capitalq/pen/xRYKaM

Comment: Hmm okay... Thanks!